# piping text file to telnet over ssh

Tags: ssh, telnet, streams

I would like to pipe a text file with commands to a telnet session I have open on a ssh client, Is this possible?
an example:
I have a text file `cmds` that contains commands like

```
FirstFunction(A,B,C,0x9001,123456,7);
SecondFunction(A,B,C1,2,4);
ThirdFunction(A,B,C,D,E,F);
```

and I can copy 7 paste each command into the telnet session I have open in a client ssh shell. can I automate this to directly stream each line into the telnet session?

**EDIT1**
On my ssh host, I open the telnet session (where the commands ha to go to ) like `telnet MyHost`

**EDIT2**
I tried:

```
$ ssh root@cc1 telnet MyHost < cmds                                                                                       
Welcome to MyHost                                                                                                              
Trying 10.254.0.2...                                                                                                                            
Connected to MyHost.                                                                                                                            
Escape character is '^]'.                                                                                                                       
Connection closed by foreign host.
ron@jpax-build07:~/tmp$
```

it doesn't seem to pipe the cmds file into the telnet session at all.
What I tried as well is:

```
$ ssh root@cc1 cmds - | telnet MyHost
Welcome to MyHost
cat: cmds: No such file or directory
telnet: could not resolve MyHost/telnet: Name or service not known
```

**EDIT 3**
I installed `expect` and tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh root@ccTest telnet -l MyHost
#expect Password:
#send "mypassword\r"
expect {-> }
send "some_cmd(20)\r"
expect {$ }
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

but this is what I got:

```
$ ./jpax_txcmd.sh 
spawn ssh root@ccTest telnet -l MyHost
bad flag "-> ": must be -glob, -regexp, -exact, -notransfer, -nocase, -i, -indices, -iread, -timestamp, -timeout, -nobrace, or --
    while executing
"expect {-> }"
    (file "./jpax_txcmd.sh" line 5)
$
```

Comment: Have you tried? `ssh … < cmds` should work. If the commands require the presence of a TTY add the `-t` flag to `ssh`

Comment: @DylanFrese Thanks for your reply, please see **EDIT 1** above, the commands have to be forwarded into the telnet session somehow...

Comment: `telnet MyHost < cmds` should do the trick, then, assuming you don't have to wait for output to come back through after all the commands are sent. If you do, try `cat cmds - | telnet MyHost`.

Comment: @DylanFrese Please see **EDIT2** above, doesn't seem to work this way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with telnet is that once it reads end-of-file it will close the connection and you will not see any output. A simple hack is to hold the input open for some extra time, eg:

```
(cat cmds; sleep 15) | ssh root@cc1 telnet MyHost
```

Obviously, this is not a robust solution, so you should use something that is able to detect when the remote has finished, for example `expect`. The following example expect script implements a typical telnet over ssh conversation involving a login for `myusername` with password `mypassword` and sending the command `ls -l` to a `$<space>` shell prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh root@cc1 telnet -l myusername myhost
expect Password:
send "mypassword\r"
expect {$ }
send "ls -l\r"
expect {$ }
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I gave it a try, please see **EDIT 3** above

Comment: @cerr There is a minor problem because the quoted string `{-> }` (i.e. `-> ` ) has been interpreted as a flag to the expect command. oops. You simply need to use `--` to signal the end of the flags, so for that line use `expect -- {-> }`

Comment: Yes, I just realized or escaping woerks too: `expect {\-> }`!